# Writing to database simultaneously from different locations with the same credentials

Tags: mysql, database

Do you foresee any difficulties in trying to submit data to my MySQL server from multiple locations, all using the same login credentials? The scenario here is that I have multiple automated data entry points and they are all using the same login.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four table columns to be concerned about here.

Just do SHOW CREATE TABLE mysql.user\G

You should see four columns named as follows:

`max_questions` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `max_updates` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `max_connections` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `max_user_connections` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

As long as these are set to 0, then there are no limits per hour to the number of times to authenticate.

As an example, these can be set on a put user basis using one of two methods:

1) UPDATE mysql.user SET max_questions=99 WHERE user='username' AND host='hostname'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

2) GRANT USAGE on ''@'' MAX_QUESTIONS=99;

Normally most people don't set these, and are this 0 by default (no limits)

Answer (score 2):

That should work fine as long as you use transactions with the appropriate isolation level for your needs.